# Permanently apply additional CSS in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

So, in Chrome, when I'm on Facebook for instance, I can inspect a certain element (the div with sponsored ads is a great example) and apply additional CSS to it. Say I'll apply `display: none;` to that element. No ads! Lovely.

But when I reload the page, the additional CSS is removed. Would there be a way to make Chrome "load" an extra stylesheet and always apply it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is finding an existing extension that loads custom js/css for particular pages. A quick search came up with this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jscript-tricks/odialddippdmebbfbflcneemfdglimod?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon. I'm sure there are others as well.